# The low speedup of written CUDA code

Tags: cuda

I written two separate code for same program in CPU (C++) and CUDA. i don't know why speedup of CUDA code is less than CPU code.
I have three matrices `H`, `E`, `F` and operations are performed on these. the speedup time in CPU code is 0.004s and in CUDA code is: 0.006s where dimensions of matrices is 32*32. in kernel code i defined three shared memory variables `matrix_H`, `matrix_E`, `matrix_F`and copied `dev_H`, `dev_E`, `dev_F` values from global memory to shared memory for speedup access time of memory and finally copied calculated shared memory variables to global memory.
it's because of a lot of parameters in kernel call or elsewhere?

```
__global__ void kernel_ScoreMatrix(char *dev_seqA, char *dev_seqB, 
   int *dev_H, int *dev_E, int *dev_F, int *dev_i_side, int *dev_j_side,
   int *dev_lenA, int *dev_idx_array, int *dev_array_length)
{
   __shared__ int matrix_H[1024];
   __shared__ int matrix_E[1024];
   __shared__ int matrix_F[1024];

   int x= threadIdx.x;
   int y= threadIdx.y;

   //calculate current_cell that execute with threads
   int current_cell = *(dev_lenA)*(y) + x;

   matrix_H[current_cell]=dev_H[current_cell];
   matrix_E[current_cell]=dev_E[current_cell];
   matrix_F[current_cell]=dev_F[current_cell];

   int index=0;

   int scoreMatrix[4];

   //for determine cells  that must compute in this time
   for (int i=0; i<*(dev_array_length); i++)
    if (current_cell== dev_idx_array[i]){
            scoreMatrix[0] = H_Matrix(current_cell, x, y, matrix_H, dev_seqA, dev_seqB, dev_lenA); 
            scoreMatrix[1] = E_Matrix(current_cell, matrix_E, matrix_H, dev_lenA);
            scoreMatrix[2] = F_Matrix(current_cell, matrix_F, matrix_H, dev_lenA);
            scoreMatrix[3] = 0;
            dev_H[current_cell] = findMax(scoreMatrix,4, index);
}
```

in main function:

```
dim3 threadsPerBlock(32, 32);
kernel_ScoreMatrix<<<1,threadsPerBlock>>>(dev_seqA, dev_seqB, dev_H, dev_E, dev_F, 
        dev_i_side, dev_j_side, dev_lenA, dev_idx_array, dev_array_length);
```

Comment: It is because you are running one block. That will only utilizes a small fraction of the total capacity of even a modest CUDA GPU. I fail to see how this question is going to be of much benefit to anyone and have voted to close it as too localised.

Comment: I'm running all threads in a block (1024 thread in a 2.x compute capability device) simultaneously. I need more blocks for 1024 threads? can you explain? unless 1024 threads does not fit in a block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A threadblock [by definition](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#hardware-implementation) executes on a single SM.  So regardless of how many threads that threadblock contains, the *only* execution resources you have available for execution of that particular threadblock are the resources in that (single) SM.  Since almost all NVIDIA GPUs contain more than a single SM, in order to keep the GPU busy (which is necessary to get the *most* performance), it's necessary to launch grids with more than 1 threadblock.  A reasonable rule of thumb is to have at least 2-4x the number of threadblocks as you have SMs, and there generally is little harm in having a lot more threadblocks than that.

But if you launch a kernel with only 1 threadblock, you are limited to 1 SM.  And therefore you are getting approximately `1/(number of SMs in your GPU)` of the performance available from the machine.  The number of threads in that threadblock does not affect this factor.